# When do you use gerunds instead of regular verbs and vice versa?

Tags: verbes

For example, if I want to stay "Running is very tiresome.", would I say:

***Courir*** est très ennuyeux.

OR

***Courant*** est très ennuyeux.

Why? Is there a specific rule that allows you to discern when to use the regular verb instead of the gerund? Or do you just have to memorize when you're supposed to use each one through repitition?

---

Also, if I wanted to say "This plan provides many benefits while minimizing loss of assets.", would I say:

*Ce plan offre de nombreux avantages tout en **minimiser** la perte d'actifs.*

OR

*Ce plan offre de nombreux avantages tout en **minimisant** la perte d'actifs.*

Note that in this second example, "minimiser" is being used as an adjective, whereas "courir" was a noun in the first example. Would that change the choice between gerund and the regular verb either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy trick that work most of the times : If you can replace your -ing verb with "*to [verb]*", you'll use an infinitive.

Note that there are other possibilities than the two you mention. Here's how it works :

> **Running** is very timesome.
>
> **To run** is very tiresome

(It's not the best way to say it but you get it)

> -> **Courir** est ennuyeux

---

> He likes to drink while he is **running**
>
> <s>He likes to drink while he is **to run**</s>

It doesn't work, you can't translate with an infinitive. In that case you need a gerund :

> Il aime boire **en courant**

But more generally, you typically use a gerund when you're using "while" or "when".

The other cases I can think of is "*running*" being translated to "*en train de courir*", or when it's an adjective or a noun it's also different ("*a running session*",...)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the sentence's construction. Here in your first sentence

> Courir est très ennuyeux

you could rephrase it as

> Il est très ennuyeux de courir

So the use of the use of the verbal form is just because you switch words in the sentence.

In your second sentence, the correct form is the second one, and it all comes from the **en** meaning that you have to use the gerund form.

> Ce plan offre de nombreux avantages tout **en** minimisant la perte d'actifs.

Edit : as @MorganFR said, watch out for some sentences where 'en' can have a different meaning

> J'ai trop de bonbons, j'aimerais en donner.

Double check if you can change the 'en' with another word, like here

> J'ai trop de bonbons, j'aimerais donner [ces bonbons].

Comment: Watch out for sentences like "j'ai trop de pertes d'actifs, j'aimerais *en minimiser* certaines", where "en" is a reference to "les pertes".

Comment: So when using "en" to mean "while", verbs acting as nouns are in gerund form (e.g: courant). But in all other cases where "en" is *not* present, verbs acting as nouns remain in their regular verb form (e.g: courir).

Would you say that is correct for the most part?

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I can't think of a counter-example so I think it covers most of cases, but stay careful as French is sometimes quite tricky

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to go by your Dutch or German intuition and to forget all about English. Kidding aside (unless you happen to speak Dutch), you would always say *courir est très ennuyeux*, because the other construction just isn't a thing.

As an aside, do you mean tiresome as in boring and tedious (which I'm quite sure is the primary meaning of *ennuyeux*) or tiresome as in physically wearying (probably *fatiguant*)? With that, on to the question:

- You use the *gérondif* to express an action that takes place at the same time as the principal verb. (I am working *while listening* to a symphony = Je travaille *en écoutant* une symphonie.) In this usage the subject of the gérondif has to be the same as that of the principal verb.
- It can be used adverbially[1] as a *complément circonstantiel* (CC) when preceded by *en*:

  - simultaneity. In this usage the CC is often preceded by *tout*, as in "Ce plan offre de nombreux avantages tout *en minimisant* la perte d'actifs."
  - cause
  - manner
  - hypothesis
  - concession
- periphrastic *aller* + *gérondif* (without *en*)

  - Son mal va s'aggravant (= continue de s'aggraver).

Source: Anne Struve-Debeaux, *Maîtriser la Grammaire française*, 2010, 3.III.2, p. 217.

Also see: http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/presentparticiple.htm

[1] *While minimizing loss of assets* is an adverbial clause. Just picking a tiny nit. ;)